# Ran out to/on the balcony

Tags: prepositions, difference

"Ran out to the balcony"

"Ran out on the balcony"

I did a search on Google and the one with "to" had three times as much hits than the one with "on", which surprised me.

Do they mean the same or is there a difference?

Comment: somehow I parsed "ran out to the balcony" as "ran towards the balcony" (which doesn't necessary mean you ended up on the balcony, but you ran towards it), whereas the latter clearly means you got there...

Comment: Need to clarify where the person is running from and to. From backstage onto the balcony? From the back of the balcony to the front? From far away from the balcony to a closer place near the balcony? Something else?  Probably want "ran out onto the balcony."

Comment: Both prepositions are fine (and others, including but not limited to ***across, onto, round, towards***). It's just a matter of exactly what ***nuance*** you want to imply (plus a healthy dollops of semantically meaningless ***stylistic choice***).

Answer (score -2):

To run - movement from inside a room to the balcony outside the room. Hence, run to.

Run 'out on the balcony' - no movement from inside a room out on the balcony. I already was there.
I decided and I ran in that place, the balcony.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not so. Ran out on the balcony is a vague sentence. It means running while on the balcony and *also* means leaving the room and going to the balcony.